# Set offset to local costmap and rotate with robot

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, local-costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

I would like to know if there is a possibility to set an offset to the local costmap in general. The problem I am facing is, my local costmap is centered at my robots footprint, however the footprint is not centered at the actual robot it is more in the of the robot. Assuming I have a costmap of width and height of 15.0 it and my footprint of the robot is 1.5 meters off the center of the robot it causes the costmap to look way more in the back than in the front of the robot.
It would be better for me if the costmap is about 2meters in the back and 13 meters (overall 15) meters in the front.

I already tried to use these parameters in the `local_costmap_params.yaml`

```
origin_x:
origin_y:
```

But it didn't change anything.

Is it somehow possible anyways?

Another question I got, is it possible to yaw the costmap with the robot, so it doesnt need to be square? Because as said before I mainly need the lookahead in the front of the robot, not too much to the sides and too much to the back.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239571/set-offset-to-local-costmap-and-rotate-with-robot/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-15**:
`costmap_2d` has a parameter called `robot_base_frame`, I think there might be something wrong with this parameter. If the frame you set for this parameter is not the center of the footprint, well, the costmap won't be in the center of the footprint.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-07-18**:
Yes, I saw this parameter. But my base frame is actually not in the center of the robot (ackermann kinematics) and also my local planer uses this parameter for controlling the platform, so I cant change this.

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-18**:
Sorry, I didn't understand what is the exact problem with setting the base frame in the center of the robot, especially the part that you said the ackermann kinematics. Can you please explain more?

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-07-25**:
Hi, by setting the parameter `robot_base_frame` in the center, also my local planner takes this point for planning with the vehicle, but with ackermann kinematics this in not correct, because the center of rotation is at the rear axle and not in the center of the robot.

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2021-03-01**:
Have you found any solution about the rotation of the costmap, so that it aligns with the robot orientation?

**Comment by [bach](https://answers.ros.org/users/66642/bach/) on 2021-07-21**:
I found a possible solution for the rotation of the costmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the center of your local costmap, a quick solution would be to move your /base_link frame, which I suppose is currently in the center of the robot, towards the rear axle.

Another solution would be to create a new frame located at the rear axle and use it instead of the /base_link for your local_costmap.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1